# Javascript variables to php variables

Tags: php, variables

I have string value in input box

```
<input name="to" value="hi.rand(1,10). my.rand(10,100).name is .rand(23,54).rand(1,4)" >
```

How to use $_GET['to'] if i want have

```
hi5 my54name is 335
```

Now i have got string "hi.rand(1,10). my.rand(10,100).name is .rand(23,54).rand(1,4)" but not execute like php function.

So how to format string in input box so PHP take it like variables.

Comment: Eek, don't.  Construct the string in PHP, don't send it from JavaScript to be eval()'d! Doing so would be a giant security hole.

Comment: a) you can use javascript rand functions. b) you can split string in server and do eval on some php codes and get their result and process it

Comment: Or construct the final string in JavaScript.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range) to find out how to generate random integers in ranges inside JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create javascript using php. Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php 
    $anyVar = "BONJOUR";    
?>
var value = "<?php echo $anyVar; ?>" ;
alert(value);
</script>
```

In the example I'm passing the value of my var $anyVar in PHP to the value var in javascript. So after the page loads and the script is parsed, you'll end up with something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var value = "BONJOUR" ;
alert(value);
</script>
```

You can as well write js code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php 
    $anyVar = "BONJOUR";    
?>
var value = "<?php echo $anyVar; ?>" ;
<?php echo 'alert(value);' ?>
</script>
```

Hope this helps.